# Facebook C# SDK after publishing not posting on wall

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I am implementing Post on Wall of friend using Facebook C# SDK, i have made separate FB apps for my localhost and for publishing server, the problem is arising is that it is working fine on my localhost,but when i am running publishing site it is not posting on wall, but showing Posted on Wall successfully( The message i am showing if wall post is successfull) i am providing AppID and AppSecret properly 
Below is my code of posting on wall of friend.

```
var fbApplication = new DefaultFacebookApplication { AppId = fbapp, AppSecret = fbsec };
                var current = new FacebookWebContext(fbApplication);

                Facebook.Web.FacebookWebClient client = new Facebook.Web.FacebookWebClient(fbtoken);                  
                dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
                parameters.message = "";
                parameters.link = "Link to my Website";
                parameters.name = "Name";
                parameters.caption = "MyTitle";
                parameters.description = "Hello World";
                parameters.from = fromId;

            object resTest = client.Post("/" + friendId + "/feed", parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

where do you get token from? Do you display authentication dialog and let user login with his/her credentials to FB?

also - when a user authorizes application to post under user's account, the request should go from "me" - assuming the user - not from "friendId".

if you have authentication token from somewhere, then here is the code I successfully use to publish on the wall:

```
var fbAPI = new FacebookApp(accesstoken);

var params = new Dictionary<string, object> { 
            { "name", "POST NAME" },
            {"caption", "test"},
            {"link", "http://www.google.com/"},
            {"description", "bla-bla-bla"},
            {"picture", imageUrl},
            {"message", "check this out!"}};

var result = fbAPI.Post("http://graph.facebook.com/me/feed", params);
```

hope that helps. Please provide more information if it does not.

Comment: If i use me then it'll post on my wall instead of my friend's wall, the token i am getting is after successfully login from FaceBook, this code is working fine on local host i am able to post on my friend's wall but when i publish it, it is not working not even on local publish

Comment: the idea is that you use accesstoken to IMPERSONATE user - and therefore "me" is used so app will publish on user's wall. Does your app have "login" popup, or do you login from the browser? is it a website? Please show complete code.

Comment: no login popup it is redirecting to facebook website for login

Comment: i've tried this solution, but still facing same problem,ie after publishing on server it is not posting on wall but on localhost it is posting well :(

Comment: well, then i would say post minimal reproducible project pls. My FB solution works well for me on multiple servers/clients.